# Paint Xfermode draws black line on android 2.2

Tags: android, android-view

I am trying to erase some part of Image, so I am Creating a custom `ImageView`, so for erasing, I am using following paint to draw

```
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(30);
    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

I am setting `XferMode` to `PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR` to clear the Image which works fine on android 4.1 but when I am testing this on android 2.3 it draws a black line instead of background color, and I also have disabled the  Hardware Acceleration,

can someone explain me why this is not working on android 2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issues and I fixed it by using Canvas.clipRect before calling super.onDraw(canvas).

This question helped me out: [Clip round from image using xfermode in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200931/clip-round-from-image-using-xfermode-in-android)

Comment: I have the same issue but not able to find a fix for that can u look at my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16229496/eraser-with-porterduff-mode-clear-always-draws-a-transparent-line