# hide one image and show other

Tags: android, touch, imageview, overlay

I have two images(above, below) place on each other. I want to hide the part of the above image where user touchs. At the end above image will completely remove and below image completely become visible.

How will I achieve this thing in Android. I am really clueless. Please help

Comment: Check out this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220354/android-touch-to-erase-portions-of-foreground-imageview-to-expose-background-v

Comment: Its just a hint type. It might help you. Add onTouchListener to you ImageView then get the x,y coordinates and use the makeRect method to show that part of the image.

Answer (score 1):

example:

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
leftButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {  
    public void onClick(View v)
        {
            image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //to set the image as invisible
            image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // to set it back to visible
        }
     });
```

hope this will help you.

Comment: He wants to hide part of the image. Not the entire image.

Comment: Oops, didn't read good enough, will look into this after diner.