# How to force GPU Rendering(Hardware acceleration) for android canvas

Tags: java, android, hardware-acceleration

I been reading in [various places](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html) and I need to enable GPU rendering for my canvas, but after adding

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

To the android manifest, it still tells me hardware acceleration(GPU rendering) is not enable....

(I use this to determine if it is enabled, yet it returns false

```
DrawingCanvas.isHardwareAccelerated()
```

)
 that There must be someone to force android to just render using the GPU instead of the CPU. I currently am using android kitkat.

Comment: "Hardware acceleration is enabled by default if your Target API level is >=14." There is clearly something wrong with your device.

Comment: This is strange.... it keeps telling me false, I wonder why.... and its a new nexus 7 unless my target API is messed up

Comment: Kitkat is API 19. You should check your configuration/drivers to see if they're working. If nothing works, try reflashing the kernel.

Comment: You know how in nthe develoepr setting you can enable it to show GPU view updates, well I did that and many things flash other than my app :(, Well I guess my option left is to use opengl es where am sure it uses the fastest rendering

Comment: That's strange. That means the GPU is working... I don't know what to tell you, I don't know why this is happening

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119753/view-ishardwareaccelerated-is-always-false are you sure you're checking `isHardwareAccelerated` AFTER attaching the canvas?

Comment: Well even if I didnt attach it, why doesnt it flash.... it should flash if GPU is enabled but the actually drawing of my canvas doesnt flash