# Hardware Acceleration supported device list?

Tags: android, hardware-acceleration

i have a question about Hardware Acceleration on Android. Do the device's android API level >= 11 means it must support Hardware Acceleration??

If not, does there exist a way to detect whether the device support Hardware Acceleration?

Thanks

Comment: Hi king Wu, did you get answer for your question? If so please tell us. Now i am facing the same problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: the same question. King Wu, did you find a solution?

Comment: Checkout [Category:Cryptographic hardware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Cryptographic_hardware) on Wikipedia.

Answer (score -1):

You can enable or desable hardware acceleration from many Level, see this link for more info visit: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html.
From View you can test hardware acceleration using for example: View.isHardwareAccelerated()

Comment: i know these description. I want to ask whether all android device must support hardware acceleration when API level >= 11