# HTML5 video player in android application not working in some phone, why?

Tags: android, html5-video

I am using HTML5 video tag with mp4 video, some phone playing this video good... nut some phone not playing this video...

**i have doubt that inside the application which video player will work to play**? have any inbuily video player or need to install any codec for that or it using browser video player?

Comment: Are you using the same OS version in all the devices? Are you hearing the sound of the video?

Comment: ya in some of tablets i can hear only sounds

Comment: Are you displaying the video fullscreen? or embedded in some other layout? What OS version are you testing on?

Comment: It is the problem with rendering on some phones coz of harware or software acceleration for rendering. Check my answer below

Comment: using video with 100% width and height, os version 4.0.3, 4.0.4,4.1...

Comment: in same version sony mobile playing the video good, but the carbon is not playing the video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses phone's codecs only. Problem is while decoding as it is not using android videoview and overlay.

Try setting harwareacceleration to true for you app. It should work. But some phones may not have hardware acceleration and so the decode fails.

But correct approach is to write the android videoplayer to play view like this:

VideoPlayerActivity.java:

package com.camera.manual;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean mResumed = false;
    private boolean mFocused = false;
    private boolean mControlResumed = false;
    private VideoView videoView = null;
    private int stopPosition = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setTheme(R.style.Theme_TransparentVideo);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);

        setContentView(R.layout.video_view);

        videoView =(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.myvideoview);
        MediaController mediaController= new MediaController(this);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView);        
        Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+R.raw.slow);        
        videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
        videoView.setVideoURI(uri);        
        videoView.requestFocus();
        videoView.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mResumed = false;
        if (mControlResumed) {
            if (null != videoView)
                videoView.pause();
            stopPosition = videoView.getCurrentPosition();
            mControlResumed = false;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mResumed = true;
        if (mFocused && mResumed && !mControlResumed) {
            if(null != videoView) {
                //videoView.resume();
                videoView.seekTo(stopPosition);
                videoView.start();
            }
            mControlResumed = true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        mFocused = hasFocus;
        if (mFocused && mResumed && !mControlResumed) {
            if (null != videoView) {
                //videoView.resume();
                videoView.seekTo(stopPosition);
                videoView.start();
            }
            mControlResumed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

video_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<VideoView android:id="@+id/myvideoview"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

and in JavaScriptInterface define a function like this:

```
public void launchVideoView () {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(mContext, VideoPlayerActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Then call this function when you have to play video

Comment: any possibility to check hardware acceleration status in phone?

Comment: Check this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/6793438/935421

Comment: This link will help you to understand more: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html